# how to relate child and parent level facts to be displayed at child level

Tags: sql-server, mdx, dax, dimensions, olap-cube

I have two facts
1)Actual
2)Plan

Actual is at child level..
Ex : orderid,product,postingdate,amount

Plan is at parent level
ex: orderid,subproduct,postingdate,amount

```
Dim-subproduct  Dim-product   
1001                100       
1002                100        
1003                100        
1004                101        
1005                102        
1006                102
```

How the relations are to be done in the cube to display like these

```
subproduct     actualamt    planamt
1001              $50        $300
1002             $150        $300
1003             $100        $300
1004             $200        $220
1004              $20        $220
1005             $100        $100
```

I have product dimension and also subproduct dimension
Please someone help me out
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please confirm if this is a multidimensional SSAS model or a tabular model? I'm a little confused by the [tag:dax] and [tag:mdx] tags both being present.

Comment: multidimensional SSAS

Comment: Create a relation between product dimension and plan on subproduct level.